# Checking if String has digits in it

Tags: java

I am trying to check if `String` has any digits in it, if there are no digits in it - print 'true' else (there are digits) print 'false'.
My code is :

```
package strings;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class P58Targil3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean sw1 = true;
        String st1 = in.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < st1.length(); i++) {
            if (st1.charAt(i) >= '0' && st1.charAt(i) <= 9)
                sw1=false;
        }
        System.out.println(sw1);
    }

}
```

This isn't working, what should I change?

Comment: Define "isn't working". Oh, 9 should be `'9'` also.

Comment: Try adding the single quote to the 9

Comment: Other way around. Don't remove the quotes around 0. Add quotes around 9.

Comment: @Shloim Oh, didn't notice I forgot them :( I added and it is working now, if instead I did the opposite and removed the quotes from '0', it will fix it neither?

Comment: @climbage Why, it will change it to false if any of them will be  a digits, it is in a for statement till the length of the String.

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1 you're right.  It's too early in the morning for me to be trying to answer questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to check whether or not a String has digits in it, is to remove all the digits from the String, and then check whether or not the resulting String is still the same length.

```
String str = "Hello123!";
System.out.println(str.length() != str.replaceAll("[0-9]", "").length());
```

This works by replacing all digits 0-9 in the String with nothing (an empty String) and then comparing that with the original. If the lengths are different you know that digits got removed, so there had to be digits to begin with.

To answer your question, you're currently checking if the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value of the character at the index of i is greater than the character value of '0' or less than or equal to the integer 9. Digits (0-9) in the ASCII encoding system are the represented with the values 48-57 with 48 being 0 and 9 being 57. So if you wanted to compare the characters values these are the conditions you could do this:

```
if (st1.charAt(i) >= 48 && st1.charAt(i) <= 57) sw1 = false;
```

but since '0' and '9' also hold those same values, you can compare them as well. So it could also be written as

```
if (st1.charAt(i) >= '0' && st1.charAt(i) <= '9') sw1 = false;
```

And also, that conditional would evaluate if the String contained digits, so you really want to initialize sw1 to false, and set it to true if it contains digits:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean sw1 = false;
    String st1 = in.next();
    for (int i = 0; i < st1.length(); i++) {
        if (st1.charAt(i) >= 48 && st1.charAt(i) <= 57) sw1 = true;
    }
    System.out.println(sw1);
}
```

Comment: There are tons of way to do it but this doesn't answer the question which is: correct the OP's code. You can add your variant afterwards but as-is this is a comment.

Comment: Nice answer, I didn't learn replaceAll or arrays yet, so I will keep it this way :) thx.

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1 I also added an detailed explanation of what was happening with your previous code. It tries to explains exactly what single quoted digits mean and why  you can just use the numbers to compare the characters.